# Why am I not getting the information from a query on the screen?

Tags: flutter

I don't know what I'm doing wrong, the truth is, I'm barely learning.
I just want to consume an api and display the information on the screen https://api.coinlore.net/api/tickers/

this is the request class

```
class Peticion extends StatefulWidget {
  const Peticion({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _PeticionState createState() => _PeticionState();
}

class _PeticionState extends State<Peticion> {
  

  Future<List<Crypto>> fetchData() async {
    final response =
        await http.get(Uri.parse('https://api.coinlore.net/api/tickers/'));

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final data = jsonDecode(response.body);
      // este es un array de Strings
      final list = data['data'] as List;
      return list
          .map((e) => Crypto(
                id: e['id'],
                name: e['name'],
                symbol: e['symbol'],
              ))
          .toList();
    } else {
      // If the server did not return a 200 OK response,
      // then throw an exception.
      throw Exception('Failed to load album');
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: FutureBuilder<List<Crypto>>(
        future: fetchData(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<Crypto>> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            final lista = snapshot.data!;
            return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: lista.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return ListTile(
                  title: Text(lista[index].name),
                  subtitle: Text(lista[index].symbol),
                  leading: Text(lista[index].id.toString()),
                );
              },
            );
          } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Text('${snapshot.error}');
          }
          return const CircularProgressIndicator();
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

here the class model

```
class Crypto {
  final String id;
  final String symbol;
  final String name;}

Crypto({
    required this.id,
    required this.symbol,
    required this.name,})

factory Crypto.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Crypto(
      id: json['id'],
      symbol: json['symbol'],
      name: json['name'],}
```

and the following happens
[image]

I will also leave the main screen in case it helps

```
return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Coinlore'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: const <Widget>[
          Peticion(),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

I would also leave the errors in the console but they are infinite and they are not specific or it is not known which one to show.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I see, it looks like an overflow issue. Basically the `Column` you're using as a parent for your `Peticion` widget, wants to grow as long as possible vertically. So there's no `constraints` or limit on it. And when the `Peticion` widget you're using gets data, it becomes a `ListView` which also wants to grow as big vertically. Now inside a infinitely growing area `ListView` just lost all it's constraints.

But yeah, just to put it simply. Try doing this

```dart
   Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Coinlore'),
      ),
      body: Peticion(),
    );
```

This will solve the issue I just mentioned. And that's what I think so far, from your code.